# Bash script redirect all output to file

Tags: linux, bash

I have following script that works fine on desktop CentOS 7, but it does not work correct on server CentOS 7 on digitalocean droplet.

The problem is that it does not auto exit on complete, I have to press enter to exit

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=/var/log/mylog.log

if [ -f $LOG_FILE ]; then
  mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_FILE.$(date +%s)
fi

exec > >(tee -a -i $LOG_FILE)
exec 2>&1

echo "track 1x"
echo "track 2x"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible way to structure this code in a way that won't trigger this race condition is to group the rest of the code inside a `{ ... }` block and pipe that to `tee`.

That way, bash will be guaranteed to `wait()` for `tee` to complete before ending the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=/var/log/mylog.log

if [[ -f "$LOG_FILE" ]]; then
  mv "$LOG_FILE" "$LOG_FILE.$(date +%s)"
fi

{
  echo "track 1x"
  echo "track 2x"
} 2>&1 | tee -a -i "$LOG_FILE"
```

Answer (score 3):

It may look like you need to press enter but you don't need to.

The issue is that the next prompt may, sometimes, appear **before** the output from process substitution with `tee` completes.  Whether the new prompt appears before or after the `tee` output depends on the vagaries of multitasking.  It may randomly appear one way or the other.

For example, I ran your script and the output looked like:

```
$ bash script
$ track 1x
track 2x
```

The second`$` is the new prompt.  The `track 1x` and `track 2x` lines are output from `tee` that appears **after** the prompt is written.  You may enter a new command without entering enter first.  I did that here for example:

```
$ bash script
$ track 1x
track 2x
date
Thu Aug  1 22:52:45 PDT 2019
```

I entered a new command, `date`, and the command was processed producing the output `Thu Aug  1 22:52:45 PDT 2019`.  It was not necessary to press enter before typing the new command.

Comment: How can I avoid this I have long script file

Comment: So, the output sometimes comes late.   Does it just look ugly?  Or, is there some reason that it is important to avoid this?

Comment: Yeah I just want to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

I added new line sleep .1 and it worked
@source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687504/redirected-output-hangs-when-using-tee

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=/var/log/mylog.log

if [ -f $LOG_FILE ]; then
  mv $LOG_FILE $LOG_FILE.$(date +%s)
fi

exec > >(tee -a -i $LOG_FILE)
exec 2>&1
sleep .1

echo "track 1x"
echo "track 2x"
```